# Why is VSCode not autocompleting my JS code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

VSCode autocompletes some things, like forEach, if, for

But if I write map, filter, reduce, it just doesn't autocomplete.

Is there a plugin for this? I'm bad remembering syntax and I'm a beginner. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe map, filter, reduce, and more were implemented in ES2015 aka ES6, so you should install es6 and es7+ extensions in the marketplace to get better intellisense

Comment: @Samathingamajig Nope, those are [ES5 methods](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16).